# Получить crash с девайса

Tags: android

На тестовом девайсе установлено мое приложение.
В какой-то момент несколько часов назад, к примеру, случился краш, пользователь нажал ОК в диалоге.

Как мне получить данные по этому крашу, если тогда девайс не был подключен к компу ?

Comment: вполне возможно, что logcat ещё помнит тот краш.

Comment: @KoVadim как тогда глянуть в логкате такой краш ?)

Comment: самый простой способ - подключить к компу, запусть adb logcat и смотреть. Или установить с playmarket приложение по слову logcat

Comment: На будущее - встройте в приложение что-то типа этого https://github.com/ACRA/acra

Comment: @metalurgus, в курсе об АКРА, есть еще Фабрик хорошая штука. Но специфика такая, что нельзя использовать эти либы :)

Comment: @KoVadim там пусто же) подключил - там показывает текущие логи девайса..

Comment: возможно, уже успели перетереться.

Comment: https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics

Comment: @temq, спасибо, я выше уже писал о ней. Но мне нужно узнать краш, который уже случился..

Answer (score 1):

Обработчик ошибок:

```
public class GarbageBugs implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler oldHandler;
    private Context context;

    public GarbageBugs(Context context) {
        oldHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
        //тут пишем код для сохранения ошибок
    }
}
```

Инициализируем его в OnCreate() вашего Application:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new GarbageBugs(this));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если есть доступ к консоле разработчика в гугле, там есть вкладка "Сбои и ANR" там можно смотреть креши